# Conditional Where clause if Left Join returns rows?

Tags: mysql, left-join, where-clause, conditional-statements

I feel like there is a way to do this using conditional Cases or Ifs, but I just can't figure it out.

The query below joins three tables together and works great if all three tables return rows.  However, there are cases where records exist in campaign_groups and new_advertisers, but none in payment_transactions.

Because of the WHERE clause making sure the payment_transactions.transaction_date >= campaign_groups.date_created, rows with zero transactions are excluded.

Is there a way to apply the WHERE clause only when the LEFT JOIN returns rows?

```
SELECT sum(payment_transactions.transaction_amount) as payment, 
            new_advertisers.account_id, 
            new_advertisers.advertiser_id,
            max(payment_transactions.transaction_date) as last_payment,
            campaign_groups.id,
            campaign_groups.date_created,
            TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, max(payment_transactions.transaction_date), NOW()) as days_passed
        FROM campaign_groups
        INNER JOIN new_advertisers ON campaign_groups.advertiser_id = new_advertisers.advertiser_id
        LEFT JOIN payment_transactions ON payment_transactions.account_id = new_advertisers.account_id
        WHERE payment_transactions.transaction_date >= campaign_groups.date_created
            AND campaign_groups.weekly_budget_cents > 0
        ORDER BY days_passed DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the condition into your ON clause:

```
LEFT JOIN payment_transactions
    ON payment_transactions.account_id = new_advertisers.account_id
    AND payment_transactions.transaction_date >= campaign_groups.date_created
WHERE campaign_groups.weekly_budget_cents > 0
```

Comment: So this works, sorta.  It works if I remove the aggregate functions in the SELECT (e.g. SUM, MAX), presumably because those fields can't be aggregated if they don't exist?

I tried adding an IFNULL to check, but that didn't help.  E.g.

    IFNULL(SUM(payment_transactions.transaction_amount),0)  as payment,

Comment: @Zach: Your query looks wrong. Are you missing a GROUP BY? When using aggregate functions it's usually a mistake to include fields in your SELECT list that aren't either in an aggregate function or in the GROUP BY clause. In fact most other databases would give you an error immediately and not even attempt to run that query. You can configure MySQL to be more strict so that it would also give an error for your query, instead of returning useless results. See here for more information: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

Comment: Ahh, that did the trick.  I needed an additional GROUP BY on new_advertisers.account_id, and an IFNULL() test on days_passed (since it would be null if no transactions were returned).  Thanks for the help!